# How do you get the rest of a hashmap as a new hashamp in clojure?

Tags: clojure, hashmap

How do you get the rest of a hasmap as a new hashamp in clojure?

if I pass a hashmap to **rest** i get back a list of vectors

```
user=> (rest { 50 "L", 10 "X", 5 "V", 1 "I" })
([10 "X"] [5 "V"] [1 "I"])
```

how can i convert that to a new hashmap?

I need a function that does this:

```
user=> (my-rest-func { 50 "L", 10 "X", 5 "V", 1 "I" })

{ 10 "X", 5 "V", 1 "I" }
```

**UPDATE**: As @AlephAleph mentions a Hashmap doesn't guarantee order, so doing a rest operation could not work as you expected.

Comment: Hash maps are unordered, why would you want to do a rest operation on a hashmap? `(dissoc your-map (first (keys your-map)))` will do what you are asking for.

Comment: I am just trying to do the roman numerals kata to learn clojure (https://codingdojo.org/kata/RomanNumerals/). 
I want to hold all the  mappings from decimal to roman in map and they should be ordere. If hash maps don't guaranty order then I guess is not the best option, any suggestions which data structure should I use?

Comment: @AlephAleph so this is how I got to solve the problem: https://github.com/asierba/Polyglot/blob/master/clojure/roman-numerals/src/roman_numerals/core.clj
But it's not pretty..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user=> (into {} (rest { 50 "L", 10 "X", 5 "V", 1 "I" }))

{ 10 "X", 5 "V", 1 "I" }
```

Comment: Though it is the answer to the question being asked, it is probably not what OP should be doing.

Comment: The question was: "how can i convert that to a new hashmap?" (into {} ...) puts the list of vectors into a new hashmap.

Comment: I agree that it is probably not what OP should be doing to solve his kata, but his actual question is straightforward and has a straightforward answer.

Comment: Even if this doesn't help me with my problem at hand - order is important to me- I would say that this technically is the answer to my question

Comment: While it seems working,  it is so just for small maps, that are represented internally as linked hash maps, hence look like sorted (by the order of keys appearance in the maps literal). But as soon as it outgrows some threshold, it would become unordered. So what is really bad, is that the solution is based on inner implementation details, that is potentially subject to change. And this change, in turn, would make your code work unpredictably.

Comment: The original question has no mention of preserving the order.

Comment: but there is obviously a context: the map is probably used for some arab to roman numerals conversion, so the order matters. And the importance of the order is confirmed by the op's question update.

Answer (score 1):

there is still a possibility for your approach using sorted maps:

```
user> (def data (into (sorted-map-by >) { 50 "L", 10 "X", 5 "V", 1 "I" }))
#'user/data

user> data
;;{50 "L", 10 "X", 5 "V", 1 "I"}

user> (def rest-data (dissoc data (first (keys data))))
#'user/rest-data

user> rest-data
;;=> {10 "X", 5 "V", 1 "I"}

user> (sorted? rest-data)
true
```